# A few question about aerospace engineering from a high school student

Tags: engineering, career, education

I am a high school student who has an intention to study Aerospace Engineering in college.

1. Does a degree in Aerospace Engineering open up a lot of career opportunities in the foreseeable future?
2. What are the possibilities of switching temporarily to different but related industries, in case this job market goes down (in a cyclic way)?
3. What are the possibilities if you have to look for opportunities abroad (constraints like nationalities, etc...)?

Comment: I was semi unsure about studying aerospace engineering as a high schooler; 5 years later I can't imagine doing anything else!

Comment: Yeah, I am almost sure that this is what I want, it is the conjecture of my great passions, physics, math, chemistry and deep space in general. I am just curious about that questions that I posted.

Comment: There may not be a single "main" language. For more on that see [What is the most popular programming language in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21948/12102) and [What software language was used to program the martian rovers Spirit, Opportunity and Curiosity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3715/12102)  and [What is the Mars Curiosity Rover's software built in?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/159637/312270) and [Interplanetary spacecraft flight operating system and programming language](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40788/12102) and

Comment: [Has in-flight software changes ever involved a change of programming language?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31132/12102) and [What space applications, projects and agencies are using the Ada programming language?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14605/12102) and [Does the Voyager team use a wrapper (Fortran(77?) to Python) to transmit current commands?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37980/12102) and [What makes Ada the language of choice for the ISS's safety-critical systems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36538/12102) and all the answers and all the links

Comment: This is just a general recommendation. Don't lock yourself too early in a narrow path for your future career. Don't rely blindly on recommendations from people of your parents' age. Their experiences may be already outdated by the time you look for a job. Keep an open mind and follow your passion(s). If you enjoy learning you will have plenty of satisfactions doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Related to question 2: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EVQXTE5U0AAxHvV?format=jpg&name=900x900  However, one question per post please, voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Different countries have different systems, but I recommend you go for something generalized like mechanical engineering for your bachelors and then specializing into aerospace engineering during a master's degree. This way you don't specialize yourself too early, and during the experience of getting that bachelor's you might come across something else that you really like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I became a mechanical engineer and worked on the Apollo program due to my intense interest in space related things.  This was not a problem in getting a meaningful job. But, due to politics in the US, there were times when aerospace was up (both civilian and military) and there were times when it was down.  When aerospace was down, in the past, environmental engineering was up.  So, to keep my economic position, it was necessary to jump back and forth several times.  I think, at the present and in the future, the frequency of this trend will only increase.

As a mech engineer, specializing in combustion related fields (chem, thermo, heat transfer, fluid mechanics, etc), I was able to move quite easily between the engineering field that was in prominence at the time and not wait out a cycle change.  I'd advocate a more traditional branch of engineering study to help during future changes in engineering fields.